# How to get type of TValue?

Tags: c++builder, rtti

I need to get the type of a `TValue`.

```cpp
TControl *control = MyForm->Controls[1337];
TRttiContext ctx;
TRttiType *type = ctx.GetType(control->ClassInfo());
TRttiProperty *property = type->GetProperty("Text"); // or "Caption", etc.
TValue result = property->GetValue(control);

if (result.IsType(tkUString)) {  
    std::cout << "String!" << std::endl;
else 
    std::cout << "NOT String!" << std::endl;
```

I get the following error:

```cpp
[bcc64 Error] Unit1.cpp(142): no matching member function for call to 'IsType'
System.Rtti.hpp(323): candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'System::TTypeKind' to 'System::Typinfo::PTypeInfo' (aka 'System::Typinfo::TTypeInfo *') for 1st argument
```

Looking at the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Rtti.TValue.IsType) `IsType()` takes a `PTypeInfo` argument (which `tkUString` is not).

But there is no C++ documentation on `PTypeInfo`, only [Delphi](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.TypInfo.PTypeInfo).

Must I include a Delphi unit in my project to use `TValue.IsType()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong method.

This is wrong:

```cpp
if (result.IsType(tkUString)) {
```

This is correct:

```cpp
if (result.Kind == tkUString) {
```